# Image K-means clustering in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have a this code for K-means clustering for image segmentation in MATLAB.  How can I display the image with (mu and mask value) ?

```
function [mu,mask]=kmeans(ima,k)
% check image 
ima=imread('Robat.jpg');
ima=double(ima); 
copy=ima;         % make a copy 
ima=ima(:);       % vectorize ima (colunm)
mi=min(ima);      % deal with negative  
ima=ima-mi+1;     % and zero values  (sefr va manfi ro az beyn mibare)
k=6;

s=length(ima); 

% create image histogram 

m=max(ima)+1; 
h=zeros(1,m); 
hc=zeros(1,m); 

for i=1:s 
  if(ima(i)>0) h(ima(i))=h(ima(i))+1;end; 
end 
ind=find(h); 
hl=length(ind); 

% initiate centroids 

mu=(1:k)*m/(k+1); 

% start process 

while(true) 

  oldmu=mu; 
  % current classification   

  for i=1:hl 
      c=abs(ind(i)-mu); 
      cc=find(c==min(c)); 
      hc(ind(i))=cc(1); 
  end 

  %recalculation of means   

  for i=1:k,  
      a=find(hc==i); 
      mu(i)=sum(a.*h(a))/sum(h(a)); 
  end 

  if(mu==oldmu) break;end; 

end 

% calculate mask 
s=size(copy); 
mask=zeros(s); 
for i=1:s(1), 
for j=1:s(2), 
  c=abs(copy(i,j)-mu); 
  a=find(c==min(c));   
  mask(i,j)=a(1); 
end 
end 

mu=mu+mi-1;   % recover real range
```

My image is a colored image and I want to apply this segmentation code to it!

Comment: Looks like you're back for some more homework solving.  This code only works for grayscale images.  If you want to go to colour images, the histogram definition is going to change.  However, you're going to have to choose what level of quantization you want, as you would need `256^3` bins which exceeds any reasonable amount of memory that most computers have.  I personally wouldn't use histograms.  You can do that without it.  I **could** modify the code, but I personally don't see any point by doing this.  It's too much work for very little gain.  I **can** however write new code :)

Comment: :) Yes . on this homework I have to compute image segmentation to gray scale and colored image.I believe that MAT LAB has a useful function for image-processing , But I must do homework without toolbox function .

Comment: This code is pretty unworkable if you want colour images.  One glaring issue is the histogram size.  If you have a white pixel, then by this code and extending to colour, your histogram will be too large: You would need an array of over 16M doubles. As such, the issue is deciding how many levels in each channel to quantize.  Another issue is how to calculate colour distances: Should you use L1? L2? Also what about colour space?  Calculating distances in RGB is very bad for capturing human perception of colour.  FWIW, this code is *really* bad for K-means.  Where in the world did you get it?

Comment: there aren't any limits for color space and calculating distance,I think  Euclidean distance metric is better:). I've found it in :http://read.pudn.com/downloads165/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/751989/kmeans-image-segmentation/kmeans.m__.htm

Comment: I won't create new code for you seeing as how it took a lot of effort for me to help you with the last one.  Instead, I will defer you to this link: http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ben-shahar/Teaching/Computational-Vision/StudentProjects/ICBV121/ICBV-2012-1-OfirNijinsky-AvivPeled/index.php.  Scroll down to the bottom to find the downloadable source code in MATLAB.  This code performs KMeans in other colour spaces.  FWIW, please don't make a habit of using established source code to do an assignment.  You don't learn anything.